# Changing background color UIIMAGE / IMAGE LATERAL

Tags: swift, image, uiimage

I have a UIIMAGE and want to change the background color of the image from Red to Black . Is there an efficient way of doing that . This is my code but it does not change the color to black

```
let image = UIImage.wrappedBundleImage("some image lateral")
image?.withTintColor(UIColor.blue)
```

Comment: UIImage or UIImageView?

Comment: UIImage  not UIImageView

Comment: U can not change Image background! It is possible to that also but needs lots of coding! Basically it would be kind of photoshop process

Comment: As @Omid said it's kind of complicated. You probably want to change the Image View's background color instead.

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14582121/replace-particular-color-of-image-in-ios?